# How can I mock a KerberosTicket instance?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, kerberos

For unit testing purposes I want to provide a mock for a javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosTicket instance. I tried using Mockito and PowerMockito but both failed with a similar message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Adding @RunWith and @PrepareForTest annotations results in following LinkageException:

```
java.lang.LinkageError:
  loader constraint violation: 
  when resolving method "sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getTicketFromSubjectAndTgs(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljavax/security/auth/kerberos/KerberosTicket;"
  the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, 
  org/epo/security/spnego/impl/KerberosUtilsTest, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) 
  for resolved class, sun/security/jgss/krb5/Krb5Util, have different Class objects 
  for the type javax/security/auth/kerberos/KerberosTicket used in the signature
```

My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

@PrepareForTest({KerberosTicket.class})
public class KerberosUtilsTest {

```
@Test
public void testGetTicketFromSubjectAndTgs() throws LoginException, KrbException, IOException {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Krb5Util.class);
    KerberosTicket kerberosTicketMock = PowerMockito.mock(KerberosTicket.class);

    AccessControlContext controlContext = AccessController.getContext();

    // Causes the LinkageError to be thrown
    when(Krb5Util.getTicketFromSubjectAndTgs(-1, "test", "test", "test", controlContext)).thenReturn(
                kerberosTicketMock);

    KerberosTicket actual = new KerberosUtils().getTicketFromSubjectAndTgs(-1, "test", "test", "test",
                controlContext);

    assertEquals(kerberosTicketMock, actual);
}
```

Searching internet revealed that the LinkageError can be fixed by changing the annotation as such:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util", "javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosTicket"})
@PrepareForTest({KerberosUtils.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

Running this gets me back to square one:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Does someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the methods of `KerberosTicket` are `final`, but PowerMockito should be able to mock them.

Don't forget to annotate your test class as required by PowerMockito to mock `final` methods

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(KerberosTicket.class)
```

and use `PowerMockito` instead of `Mockito` inside a test

```
KerberosTicket mock = PowerMockito.mock(KerberosTicket.class);
PowerMockit.when(mock.getAuthTime().thenReturn(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I already added the RunWith and PrepareForTest but faced different errors, that's why I started removing them. Re-adding them again gives this error:

    java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getTicketFromSubjectAndTgs(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljavax/security/auth/kerberos/KerberosTicket;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class,

Comment: org/epo/security/spnego/impl/KerberosUtilsTest, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, sun/security/jgss/krb5/Krb5Util, have different Class objects for the type javax/security/auth/kerberos/KerberosTicket used in the signature

I've add my test code to the question.